# How to write sum function by functional programming in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, reduce, fold

```
def f(x: Int): Int = x + 1

def sum1(n: Int): Int = {
   var sum: Int = 0
   for (i <- 1 to n) {
     sum += i * f(i)
  }
  sum
}

val sum2: Int => Int = (n: Int) => (1 to n).reduce((x, y) => x * f(x) + y * f(y))
```

The sum2 functions is wrong but I wonder how to write sum1 by using reduce or fold

Comment: `(1 to n).fold(0)((s,x) => s + x * f(x))`

Comment: `(0 to n).reduce((s,x) => s + x * f(x))`

Comment: I've just figured it out, if I want to do it with range (1 to n) actually I need (0 to n). It would be (0 to n).reduce((x, y) => x + y * f(y))

Comment: yeah that would be true, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's generally safer to just use `fold` because the edge case is already baked into the signature while `reduce` will fail on an empty list (which is why you need to start from 0 instead of 1)

And that's a perfectly fine solution. However because Scala is an expressive language, there are many ways to achieve the same result. For example, you can also separate the step of computing `f(x)` from the step of summing every thing together, which looks like this

```scala
(1 to n).map(x => x * f(x)).fold(0)(_ + _)
// or using sum like jwvh suggested
(1 to n).map(x => x * f(x)).sum
```

Comment: `.fold(0)(_+_)` is the same as `.sum` but, either way, it's not the same results as the `sum1()` results.

Comment: you're right, missed the multiplication. Thanks for pointing out, i edited the answer btw